# MapControls for UNO Platform

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml, uno-platform

I'm trying to display a map using UNO Platform, I follow the sample code stated https://platform.uno/docs/articles/controls/map-control-support.html

I have no problem to run it on UWP, but for Android, I deployed to emulator, it just show the slider, no map shown. I have my GoogleMap API and insert per the instruction.

Anyone know why it doesn't work ?
Actually, it doesn't work for wasm too.

Comment: Could you try running your app on a real device and see how it goes? Some emulator configuration cause issue to render the map this is why it'd be good to know if this is an emulator issue or not.

Comment: Try on HTC U11 device with Android 9.0, no luck on the map show.

Comment: Could you tell me what version of Uno.Platform are you using?

Comment: For Android, make sure you are installing the latest **Uno.UI.Maps** (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Uno.UI.Maps/) which will only show if you check on the "Include Prereleases" checkbox.